# I have installed Numpy but PyCharm can't find the module

Tags: python, numpy

When I run `import numpy as np`

I get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'`

I have tried it in the project I always used, I have tried it in a new project where Conda is the environment used but I always get this error. I am clueless here.

When I type in the Terminal of my Macbook `pip3 install numpy` I get the answer that I already have numpy `Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages (1.21.5)`

Comment: Instead of using `pip`, why not use `PyCharm` to do the  installs? You need to check in the settings which version of python that `PyCharm` is using for your project and make sure that `numpy` is installed there.

Comment: @quamrana If I type in the Terminal PyCharm install numpy it says command not found: PyCharm. Python 3.10 is used. How do I make sure that numpy is installed there? Edit: Now I tried pip3.10 install numpy and it installed something and I think with the Environment of Conda it actually works now

Comment: No, not on the command line. I meant within the `PyCharm` IDE. There are settings for your project: Use: `File/Settings ...  Project/Python Interpreter` and you will see the python interpreter used, plus all the installed packages. From there you can add more packages.

Comment: @quamrana Anyway it works now in the Conda environment after I ran pip3.10 install numpy in the terminal, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Often, many IDEs (like Spyder, Jupyter Notebook, or PyCharm) installs their own virtual environment of python to keep things easy and simple for them from your global python.
even if you have a package installed in your global python, you might not able to use it in your virtual environment since it would have separate package management.
So the solution is to install the package using the IDEs.
In your case you can do it by using their terminal or using the red bulb (which will appear on the top of your pakage)
[image]

Comment: Jupyter doesn't create a virtual environment